# uploading a binary file using POST request

Tags: c#, file, upload, binary

If we want to upload a file, whether we have to add the Content Disposition header in the content part of the http request? Please clarify.

Http request will contain only header part and content part only?

Comment: what class do you use to upload a file? `Content-Disposition` is splitting the body of your HTTP post into multiple chunks.